# Naive Bayes ValueError: Dimension Mismatch

Tags: python, naive-bayes-classifier

I am attempting to make predictions of categories of text data, one of which is Naive Bayes. The training data contains 7 categories, 802 data points. After balancing with SMOTE all 7 categories now have 134 data points for a total of 938.

Training Data:

```
df_train['Categories'].value_counts()

Category 1         134
Category 2         130
Category 3         128
Category 4         106
Category 5         103
Category 6         101
Category 7         100


X = df_train['Element']
y = df_train['Categories']

count_vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))
X_vect = count_vect.fit_transform(X)
print(X_vect.shape)
X_res, y_res = sm.fit_resample(X_vect, y)
print(X_res.shape)

(802, 747)
(938, 747)
```

My test data to be predicted upon contains 46 text elements that vectorizes into 280 features.

```
df_test_bagofwords = count_vect.transform(df_test['Elements'])
print(df_test_bagofwords.shape)

(46, 280)

mnb = MultinomialNB().fit(X_res, y_res)
mnb_pred = mnb.predict(df_test_bagofwords)

ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

When attempting the same with SVM I get further information:

```
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 280 should be equal to 747, the number of features at training time
```

I thought count_vect.transform() would fit the test data to the vectorized and fitted training data. But this error is consistent.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I'm not sure what happens but I think that using SMOTE with Naive Bayes is a bad idea: first resampling is rarely useful anyway, but more importantly this will completely mess up the prior probability which is an essential part in NB.

Comment: Thank you for your input. The use of class balancing and its impact on modeling is something I’ll look into. Some of the categories have severe class imbalance. And I’m using more models than just NB. That said, I encounter the same error on the data whether I have addressed class imbalance or not.

Comment: There's something strange about the 2nd dimension of the test set: it should be the same as for the training set (747) but it's 280 instead. Are you sure that you're using the same `count_vect` object initialized on the training set with `fit_transform`?